# How to preserve spaces in data(4spaces) for a column while writing to a csv file in pyspark

Tags: string, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a an input csv file with one record. When I read the file in pyspark, the dataframe has three columns a, b, c respectively. a and c has data and b has data that is 4 spaces. While writing the file to csv, the 4 spaces data is lost and it is writing to the file as empty string.

Input file:

```
aaaa,    , bbbb
```

Output file:

```
aaaa,"", bbbb
```

How can I preserve the 4 spaces data as is.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark SQL removing white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021073/spark-sql-removing-white-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

When writing you need to set the options:

```
df.write
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false")
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "false")
  .csv(path)
```